# Dynamic form field read-only not working

Tags: lightning-app-builder, lightning-page

I have created a dynamic form and made a field read-only in it.
But when I see a record the field is editable.

I have created a field section and added the field in the section.

I have cleared cache and tried in different browser.

Do I need to do anything else ?

Answer (score 4):

You probably have the "Edit Read Only Fields" permission.

See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335725&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1.

> Users are able to edit fields which are 'Read Only' as per Field Level Security or on the Page layout. This behavior is seen if the Profile associated with the User has 'Edit Read Only Fields' selected.

Comment: I would suggest to include some more details just in case the link goes dead in future.

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MenachemShanowitz

Answer (score -1):

As a system administrator, one can always see READ_ONLY fields.
Try to test as a non-admin user.

Comment: The question was about editing fields,  not seeing them. Note also the question is 3 years old.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/210949)